# Extend mysqli_result - Does it use store_result() or use_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote a child of mysqli with a query method that returns a child of mysqli_result. This result child will have additional methods unique to my app.

```
public MySQL extends mysqli
{
    public function query($query)
    {
        if ($this->real_query($query)) {
            if ($this->field_count > 0) {
                return new MySQL_Result($this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

class MySQL_Result extends mysqli_result
{
    public function fetch_objects() {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $this->fetch_object())
            $rows[$row->id] = $row;
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is whether `fetch_object()` uses buffered or unbuffered SQL data.

The constructor of `mysqli_result` isn't visible in `mysqli.php`, so I can't see if its calling `$mysqli->store_result()` or `$mysqli->use_result()`.

I tried adding these methods to `MySQL` but neither function is echoed.

```
    public function store_result($option='a') {
        echo "STORE RESULT<br/>";
    }

    public function use_result($option='a') {
        echo "USE RESULT<br/>";
    }
```

Does this mean that the `mysqli_result` constructor doesn't call either? If so, how does it access the SQL data when `fetch_object` is called?

I want buffered SQL data. If I can't figure out what the child constructor is doing, I may have to replace the result child class with a decorator that calls `$mysqli->store_result()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is neither. The constructor of `mysqli_result` doesn't call any of these methods. However, `mysqli_query()` internally calls `mysql_store_result()` or `mysql_use_result()` which are C level API functions. Even if you extend mysqli class, you won't see your new methods getting called though. You have to understand that mysqli extension is written in C, not in PHP. The way that the code is written cannot be expressed in PHP very easily.

If you are using `mysqli::real_query()` to execute SQL then you need to take care of calling either `mysqli_store_result()` or `mysqli_use_result()` function yourself. Of course, these functions will return `mysqli_result` object instead of your `MySQL_Result` one. It's going to be impossible to inherit from this class.

You can use composition instead of inheritance. You would pass `mysqli_result` object you get from either of these two functions into the constructor of your `MySQL_Result` class.

For example:

```
class MySQL
{
    private mysqli $mysqli;

    public function __construct(string $host, string $username, string $passwd, string $dbname)
    {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname);
    }

    public function query(string $query): MySQL_Result | bool
    {
        if ($this->mysqli->real_query($query)) {
            if ($this->mysqli->field_count > 0) {
                return new MySQL_Result($this->mysqli->store_result());
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MySQL_Result
{
    public function __construct(private mysqli_result $result)
    {
    }

    public function fetch_objects()
    {
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = $this->result->fetch_object()) {
            $rows[$row->id] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

**Important:** The functionality that you require is already available with PDO. If you don't have a good reason to use mysqli, try using PDO instead.

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_result` [uses buffered results from MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) (emphasis mine)

> **Queries are using the buffered mode by default.** This means that query results are immediately transferred from the MySQL Server to PHP and then are kept in the memory of the PHP process. This allows additional operations like counting the number of rows, and moving (seeking) the current result pointer. It also allows issuing further queries on the same connection while working on the result set. The downside of the buffered mode is that larger result sets might require quite a lot memory. The memory will be kept occupied till all references to the result set are unset or the result set was explicitly freed, which will automatically happen during request end the latest. The terminology "store result" is also used for buffered mode, as the whole result set is stored at once.

The process is this

1. You perform a query. MySQL sends back a result
2. `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_get_result` (prepared statements) will load this data set into a `mysqli_result` object

You actually have to go out of your way to perform async queries

Comment: Except that I overloaded the "query" method in MySQL and called real_query(). So nothing is returned from SQL. The return must happen in the mysqli_result constructor or in fetch_object().

Answer (score -1):

It appears that mysqli_result is using buffered SQL data.

I wrote a test-case that alternately accesses rows from two queries. If the data was unbuffered, the SQL server would have been busy and unable to answer the 2nd query.

```
/* Open a connection */
$mysqli = new MysqlDB("127.0.0.1", "phpuser", "phpuserpw", "wishlist");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   return;

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM wishers")) {

    $res2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM wishes");

    echo "Mem = ".memory_get_usage()."<br/>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $row2 = $res2->fetch_row();

        printf ("1: ID=%s,  Name=%s, Pass=%s<br/>",$row[0],$row[1], $row[2]);
        printf ("2: ID=%s,  WisherID=%s<br/>", $row2[0], $row2[1]);

        echo "Row Mem = ".memory_get_usage()."<br/>";
    }
```

1: ID=1, Name=Tom, Pass=tomcat

2: ID=3, WisherID=2

1: ID=2, Name=Jerry, Pass=jerrymouse

2: ID=4, WisherID=2

1: ID=6, Name=Tommy, Pass=tomcat

2: ID=5, WisherID=1

..........................

Since both queries work, the data must be buffered.